# Microsoft BOT Framework BOT is stopped working intermittently

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am facing intermittent issue in BOT.

I have two bots which are written using c# and BOT Framework V4 and both are same and are hosted on IIS.

Also i have hosted two WebChat Node.js applications and both are same.

I have two different Azure registration for two bots.

One bot is constantly throwing issue and it stops working intermittently. Then we have to recycle its application pool to make it start again.

Server : Windows Server 2012 R2 
IIS : 8.5.9600

The error is given below,

```
fail: EnterpriseTestBot.Startup[0]
      Exception Occured :-> The operation was canceled.-----   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TemplateManager.TemplateManager.ReplyWith(ITurnContext turnContext, String templateId, Object data)
         at EnterpriseTestBot.Dialogs.Main.MainDialog.OnStartAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Test\BOT\Enterprise_BOT\EnterpriseTestBot\Dialogs\Main\MainDialog.cs:line 101
         at EnterpriseTestBot.Dialogs.Shared.RouterDialog.OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Test\BOT\Enterprise_BOT\EnterpriseTestBot\Dialogs\Shared\RouterDialog.cs:line 35
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at EnterpriseTestBot.EnterpriseTestBot.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Test\BOT\Enterprise_BOT\EnterpriseTestBot\EnterpriseTestBot.cs:line 96
         at EnterpriseTestBot.Middleware.GetSetUserDataMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Test\BOT\Enterprise_BOT\EnterpriseTestBot\Middleware\GetSetUserDataMiddleware.cs:line 98
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AutoSaveStateMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at EnterpriseTestBot.Middleware.SetLocaleMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Test\BOT\Enterprise_BOT\EnterpriseTestBot\Middleware\SetLocaleMiddleware.cs:line 49
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)-----System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadBufferedAsyncCore(Memory`1 destination)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.RawConnectionStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)
         at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
         at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
         at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
info: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration[0]
      Sending activity.  ReplyToId: 5Ly5VgcOJHH
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://TestBot.MyCompany.com/ATOM/api/messages application/json; charset=utf-8 377
info: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration[0]
      Received an incoming activity.  ActivityId: 6WV3KIRaT3y
info: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration[0]
      Sending activity.  ReplyToId: 6WV3KIRaT3y
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular kind of issue needs to be raised on GitHub (https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet) because it's going to be specific to your bot.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.